# Can the Ardent's Unhinging strike cause a creature to target itself?

Tags: dnd-4e, targeting, psionics, ardent

The power reads:

> At-Will        Augmentable, Charm, Psionic, Psychic, Weapon
>
> Standard Action      Melee weapon
>
> Target: One creature
>
> Attack: Charisma vs. Will
>
> Hit: Charisma modifier psychic damage, and the target makes a melee basic attack as a free action against a creature of your choice.

Does "a creature of your choice" include "attack yourself?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes, it can target itself

**Choosing Targets** (p105 of the *Rules Compendium*) tells us that a target must meet the following criteria:

- The target must be valid
- The target must be within range
- The target must be within line of effect

Later on, valid targets are defined further, of note:

> The simplest target definition is "one creature," which means a single creature of any type.

The target of a melee basic attack is "one creature."  Therefore a creature can chose to target itself with a melee basic attack should it so desire.

"a creature of your choice" is not functionally different from "one creature" so **Unhinging Strike** will work to have the creature target itself.

Comment: ...or to have the creature target you, even.