# Can I make a creature target itself with a Melee Basic Attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, targeting

Hypnotism (Heroes of Fallen Lands p205):

> **Hit:** [...] The target uses a free action to make a melee basic attack against a creature of your choice[...]

Friendly Fire (Dragon 384):

> **Effect:** The target repeats the attack as a free action against a creature you choose within 2 squares of the target of its original attack. The new target must still be legal for the attack.

Can I make the target of Hypnotism  or Friendly Fire target itself with the MBA?

Comment: Related (unless I'm missing something): [Can the Ardent's Unhinging strike cause a creature to target itself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/5685/52137), [Can the target of Drunken Monkey attack themself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13385/52137)

Comment: @Someone_Evil, related, yes, but they give opposing answers

Comment: Related: my older brother grabbing my fist and hitting me with it. About a million times.

Comment: @nitsua60 is this really a thing? I have only seen it in American films

Comment: @András ohmigosh, absolutely. "Stop hitting yourself. Stop hitting yourself. Why are you hitting yourself?"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes.

First, it's important to differentiate the two powers.  Friendly Fire is clearly yes, as long as it is within 2 squares of its original target- the target is 1) a creature and 2) within two squares of the target of its original attack.

With Hypnotism, there are two arguments against, as noted in "[Can the target of Drunken Monkey attack himself?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/13385/52137)"

The first argument is whether a power needs to specify that the creature can target itself.  This is necessary if a power specifies "allies," because you are not your own ally, or if it is a Close Burst, because Close Burst powers by rule exclude the caster/monster making the attack.  But otherwise, there is no requirement for it to specify; a creature is still a creature.

The second argument against comes from PHB1's rule about Melee 1 (pg 56):

> Melee 1: A melee power that has a range of 1 can be used only on an adjacent target.

In this case, there is no official rule as to whether or not a creature is adjacent to itself, so it would be possible that a creature couldn't attack itself with a Melee 1 attack.  But that text was superseded by the Rules Compendium, page 100:

> Melee [number]: The power can be used against a target that is within
>   the specified number of squares of the power’s origin square. For example,
>   a melee power that has a range of 1 can normally be used only against an
>   adjacent target, whereas a melee power that has a range of 0 can be used
>   only against a target sharing the attacker’s space.

Clearly, a creature is within 1 square of itself (in fact it is actually within 0 squares of itself).  So while it's not clear that it's an adjacent creature, that is no longer a requirement of melee 1, and they can make the attack.

Answer (score -3):

Yes.  It would still need to make an attack roll and then damage roll.  I did that in a campaign I ran a while ago.

Comment: Can you support this by quoting the rules of D&D 4e? This is a rules question so answers need to address the rules first (other experiences and house-rules come second, or possibly third, to that)